Use Plasma theme with PySide6
I changed my application to use PySide6 instead of PyQt5. With PyQt5, it used my KDE Plasma theme, but with PySide6, it uses the Fusion style. This also happens with PySide2. How do I make it use my theme from Plasma?
I'm running KDE Neon 6.0 with KDE Plasma 6.0.5

Qt is normally able to detect the current KDE configuration, but that depends on how it's installed (specifically, how PySide was installed and if/how it installed its own Qt builds). It's possible that the installed system styles are not compatible with the Qt libraries used by PySide due to version/linking issues. 1. How did you install PySide; 2. what is the output of QStyleFactory.keys()?

@musicamante I installed it with pip in a venv. I also tried without a venv but the same applies. I think PyQt5 was installed via apt, but I don't think there's a PySide6 package in the ubuntu repos. The output of QStyleFactory.keys() is ['Windows', 'Fusion']
